# unable to access php file nginx

Tags: php, nginx, server, web-hosting, fastcgi

I am completely new to nginx .
I have project based on angular js which have a index.html, and on a certain event i perform a angular http request to x.php file and fetches the response from it.
Its running perfect on my local system and a apache based private hosting  server.
I created a free tier ec2 instance and started a centos based linux instance on which i hosted the code and installed nginx .
Here is my nginx config

```
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name  mydomain.co.in www.mydomain.co.in;

   location / {
     root   /var/www/html/indm;
     index  index.php index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string =404;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
   }
   error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
```

At first it was giving me 500 gateway error when the http request was performed on that php file. I check in the XHR request.Here is the error in nginx error.log

```
[error] 17193#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 42.111.38.254
```

I searched a bit and changed appended a "=404" to try uri statement. But now it redirect to a 404 . I want to run that php file. 
the server 
Nginx server is running
php fpm is also running

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The `location ~ \.php$` block has no root. Move the `root` statement into the `server` block so that the same value is inherited by both `location` blocks.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    root   /var/www/html/indm;

    location / {
        ...
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: U made my day :)

Comment: can you help on this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436579/trailing-slash-redirection-issue-nginx