# Trailing slash/redirection issue NGINX

Tags: nginx, server, url-rewriting, redirect, http-redirect

I am using Drupal 8 with nginx . I have a multiProject Environment with single domain.
I have 10 Drupal sites. which works as 
https://example.com/site1
https://example.com/site2
Each site has its on distinct docker container and everything is running smooth on production. But I noticed A issue with few sites. They give 404 without a trailing slash .Only 4 of them. Rest six automatically appends the slash when I remove them and hit in browser.
The nginx config for all are exactly same.
Here is the nginx config for  a site :

```
server
   {
   client_max_body_size 128m;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   location /site1 {
      try_files $uri/ $uri /site1/index.php?$query_string;
   }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 403 /403.html;
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi_params;
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
     proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
  }
}
```

I have tried every thing , rewrite, try files and returns. 
can any one help.

Comment: The presence of a directory with the same name will influence whether the `$uri/` term appends a trailing slash.

Comment: the directory is present.....is this may be some kind of a permission issue?...also when i manually append the '/', it works fine